# How to replace a string only if the line starts with another string

Tags: search, gvim, replace

I need to find ONLY the lines that start with the string `G1 Z`, and then replace any occurrence on that same line of `F1800` with a new value of `F500`. For example:

```
G1 Z9.800 F1800.000 ; move to next layer (48)
G1 X103.711 Y99.145 F1800.000 ; move to first perimeter point
G1 X96.289 Y96.289 E320.13685 ; perimeter
G1 Z0.000 F1800.000 ; move to next layer (49)
G1 X103.711 Y96.289 E320.44978 ; perimeter
G1 X103.711 Y99.070 E320.56702 ; perimeter
G1 X95.782 Y104.218 E321.13977 F1800.000 ; perimeter
```

Should become:

```
G1 Z9.800 F500.000 ; move to next layer (48)
G1 X103.711 Y99.145 F1800.000 ; move to first perimeter point
G1 X96.289 Y96.289 E320.13685 ; perimeter
G1 Z10.000 F500.000 ; move to next layer (49)
G1 X103.711 Y96.289 E320.44978 ; perimeter
G1 X103.711 Y99.070 E320.56702 ; perimeter
G1 X95.782 Y104.218 E321.13977 F1800.000 ; perimeter
```

I know `/^G1 Z` will find these lines, and `%s/F1800/F500/g` will replace ALL F1800s, but I can't see how to restrict the replace to the lines starting with that string.

I'm on GVIM 8.0.586.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
:g/^G1 Z/s/F1800/F500/g
```

The `:g` is the "global" command. It selects lines with a regular expression and then executes a command on it.

Here it selects lines that start with `G1 Z` and then substitutes all "F1800" with "F500" in this line.

BTW:

- The default command for `:g` is `print`. So by just executing `:g/^G1 Z/` Vim will print all lines that start with `G1 Z`.
- There is also the `:v/.../` command. It selects all lines that does not match the given regular expression.

See `:help multi-repeat`.

Answer (score 2):

The following command uses look behind regex pattern:

```
:%s/\v(^G1 Z.*)@<=F1800/F500/g
```

- `%s` starts the substitution in the whole file.
- `/` starts the find part of the find and replace.
- `\v` enables `very-magic` (see `:h /magic`)
- `(^G1 Z.*)@<=` looks behind for lines starting with `G1 Z`. But it doesn't start the matching. (see `:h /\@<=`)
- `F1800` starts matching for, well, `F1800`.
- `/` starts the replace part of find and replace.
- `F500` replaces the matched pattern
- `/` finishes the replace pattern
- `g` is for global substitution, so that all the instances of `F1800` will be replaced by `F500`. (see `:h :s_flags`)

Comment: Can also use `\zs`. e.g. `:%s/^G1 Z.*\zsF1800/F500/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation. I found the other answer easier to follow.

Comment: @PeterRincker but that wouldn't work if there are more than one F1800 in a line

Comment: @Davo yes. I just wanted to see if I could get the solution. I learnt about `@<=` today. Although I know using `:g/pattern/cmd` is more intuitive in cases like this. By the way, does it work?

Comment: Yes, both answers and @PeterRincker's example all worked. :)